# How to send at-commands to tcp port and retrieve response

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, byte

I am writing Python code to receive information from tcp port 20001. According to the documentation , there are some AT-commands that can be called. One of them is `+OK`. Also, the AT command end bit must be `0x0D`

[image]

[image]

I followed the example [here](https://medium.com/@dillan.teagle.va/sending-binary-commands-to-devices-in-python-60d64dc02c44) and wrote the code below to send the command and receive the response

```
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 20001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
print('connected')
# won't work without encoding
packet = bytearray('x1b' + '+OK' + 'x1d', encoding='ascii')
s.send(packet)
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
print(data)
```

It connected successfully but I am not getting any data back. I highly doubt I got the `packet` part right. The example didn't have the encoding part. But it won't work without encoding (typeerror string argument without an encoding). And do I need `AT` in front of `+OK`? Never worked with AT command before and there aren't many examples out there.

#### EDIT

The returned connection information looks like this:
[image]

Comment: The `"AT"` commands look like the old modem/GSM commands. What makes you think this is something to do with TCP sockets?

Comment: @quamrana What else can it be if it is not TCP? It connects using `socket.SOCK_STREM` which is specific to TCP

Comment: I mean that the picture shows an example `"AT"` command and the link shows the escape (`'x1b'`) usage. What connects the two?

Comment: @quamrana, honestly I don't know what that `x1b` means from the link. I just know it has to end with `x0d`. What is the correct way to construct the command string for AT commands?

Comment: So you're just combining two random things hoping they will work?

Comment: I didn't think it was random. Just thought I need to send a command to the port and receive the data. The example was the closest I could find. I removed the `x1b` part from the string and it is still not getting anything

Comment: So what is it about that port that makes you think that an `"AT"` command is needed?

Comment: @quamrana I added an image from the document. It clearly says "AT command interface is at port 20001

Comment: And what is this `"NDC-01"` device? You haven't mentioned that up until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> packet = bytearray('x1b' + '+OK' + 'x1d', encoding='ascii')
> ```

Based on the protocol description the packet should be b'AT+OK?\r' only.

Also, based on your feedback the `s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)` seems to confuse the server since it thinks that the client has closed the connection, even though the client is still waiting for data. So you might need to leave this line out.

Comment: I am still not getting any data

Comment: @ddd: I have no idea what your current code is, I only can see the wrong code from your question. Therefore it's impossible to tell what is wrong. Maybe provide your current code in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or so. Also please provide a more clear error description apart from "not getting any data"? Do you get any errors? Does the program hang or simply exit? ...

Comment: @ddd: Also, why do you think that the examples from the the external article even match the protocol spoken with your device? I have no documentation for your device but based on the small snipped you included I suggest that the packet should only be something like `"AT+OK?\n"` or maybe `"AT+OK?\r\n"` or `"AT+OK?\r"` depending on the kind of line ending used.

Comment: I changed that packet line to `packet = bytearray('\x1b' + '+OK' + '\x0d', encoding='ascii')
`. It just hangs at `data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)` with nothing printed out. According to the document,  the AT command end bit must be `0x0D`. I have no idea my device is using the same protocol as that example. but that was the only thing I could find about sending command and receive response

Comment: I ran `nmap -p- localhost` to scan all the open ports and confirmed 20001 is tcp

Comment: @ddd: TCP is just a means to transport bytes. You need to speak the application protocol required by the server the same as you need to speak a language understood by some other person if you want to communicate with the person. You cannot expect the server to react whatever you chose to speak, only to what language the server understands. Therefore follow the documentation - whatever it contains (unknown to us)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253501/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-ddd).